# Why if statement is not working in the code, while else if statement works?

Tags: java

I am working on strings for a while.
I have a code of toggle case, i.e. a program to convert lower case to upper and vice versa. I'm getting a problem with the condition checking. If I don't use else if, I am getting all lower case and when I use else if, i get my program working correctly. please see whats wrong. Thank you in advance.

Working code:

```
public class ToggleCase
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String s = "We ArE THe BeSt", s1 = "";
        
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<s.length(); i++)
        {
            char ch = s.charAt(i);
            if(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') ch= (char)(ch-32);
            else if(ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') ch= (char)(ch+32); // main statement
            
            s1 += ch;
        }
        System.out.println("Toggle case: "+s1);
    }
}
```

Non-working code:

```
public class ToggleCase
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String s = "We ArE THe BeSt", s1 = "";
        
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<s.length(); i++)
        {
            char ch = s.charAt(i);
            if(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') ch= (char)(ch-32);
            if(ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') ch= (char)(ch+32); //change is here
            
            s1 += ch;
        }
        System.out.println("Toggle case: "+s1);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is with your second if condition, your ```ch``` is already uppercased before it.  So  when the system encounters this second ```if``` condition, it matches so it changes the upper case  to lower case..

Comment: Because in the first code, only one of the two statement will be reached (either the `if(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')` or `if(ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') ` precisely because of the `else` keyword. But in the second code, both of them will be reached, and after the first one ch will be changed to uppercase, so it will be changed back to lower case. The first code is the good approach.

Comment: The "non-working" code will first flip any lowercase value of `ch` to uppercase, and then for the second if, `ch` always has an uppercase value, so it will flip everything back to lowercase.

Comment: Not related to the problem, but don't build up strings using `+=`: append to a `StringBuilder` (or just manipulate the `char[]` returned by `s.toCharArray()` directly).

Comment: @user16320675 the improvements made to the performance of a single string concatenation still don’t change the fact that *repeatedly* performing a string concatenation (especially for each character) is expensive. It has quadratic time complexity, compare to the linear time complexity it should have. Also known as [Shlemiel the painter’s algorithm](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/#:~:text=code%20uses%20the-,Shlemiel%20the%C2%A0painter%E2%80%99s%20algorithm,-.%20Who%20is) By the way, when using Eclipse, you still don’t get the improvement implemented by Java 9+ `javac`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your current character is 'a', that is the character value 97. In your non-working code the first 'if' statement matches the char, so you subtract 32. Now ch has the value of 65. This represents the character 'A'.
So the second 'if' statement matches again and raises the character value back to 97.